# Cannot render content after loading variables into hooks from AsyncStorage (react-native/expo)

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, hook, asyncstorage

I'm developing my first app in react-native (expo). I did the flow of authentication and I'm using AsyncStorage to keep/manage the user info and jwt token.

I did the first window for the logged user but I couldn't render the "Hello username" message.

First, I did this storage function to manage the user and token info:

```js
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const storage = () => {
  const login = (user, jwt) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
    AsyncStorage.setItem("authToken", `Bearer ${jwt}`);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("user");
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("authToken");
  };

  const register = (user, jwt) => {
    login(user, jwt);
  };

  const getUser = async () => {
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");

    return JSON.parse(user);
  };

  const getAuthToken = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("authToken");

    return token;
  };

  return { login, logout, register, getUser, getAuthToken };
};

export default storage;
```

The component, that I called OverviewScreen looks like this:

```js
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import storage from '../utils/storage';

export default function OverviewScreen() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const { getUser } = storage();

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser().then((u) => {
      setUser(u);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="flex-1 items-center justify-center">
      {!user ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <Text>Hello {user.username}</Text>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>)
}
```

I added a useEffect to print when user state change (`if (user) console.log(user)`), and it is working fine. Also I tried to do the same behaviour writing the useEffect like this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserAsync = async () => {
      const u = await getUser();
      setUser(u);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    getUserAsync();
  }, []);
```

And I obtained the same result.

Could someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my fault.

The OverviewScreen was being rendered by a Tab.Screen and I used the prop children instead component to refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

lets change

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUser().then((u) => {
      setUser(u);
    });
  }, []);
```

to

```
useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("user")
      then(result => {
         setUser(JSON.parse(result))
      })
  }, []);
```

then see the result

Comment: Same result, the getUser call do the same `JSON.parse`

Comment: To check that, I added another useEffect like this:
`useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user);
  }, [user]);`
and it prints first null, and second prints all the user info, so I understand that the getUser func is working fine.